# html entities being reported as something different than what the string actually has

Tags: php

This is strange. I have the following string:

```
Booker’s
```

Each character's coordinate:

```
66    <-B
111   <-o
111   <-o
107   <-k
101   <-e
114   <-r
226   <-â (Latin small letter a with circumflex)
128   <-€ (euro sign)
153   <-™ (Trademark sign)
115   <-s
```

Why am I getting the Latin small letter a with circumflex, euro sign and the trademark sign in place of the `’`? What I need is the Right single quotation mark (`’`) so I can convert it to utf8.

EDIT:

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

In a function that I have to convert the quotes to utf8:

```
function convertQuote($string){
  return str_replace( '’', "'", $string );
}
```

The output of the function gives me exactly what I started with and nothing is converted:

```
Booker’s
```

Comment: What are your encoding settings? A bit of code to show where this string is coming from would be helpful as well.

Comment: @André, I've already got a utf8 php header at the top of the page.

Comment: @NaN: How do you receive the string? Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: The string is in a POST array, generated by AJAX

Comment: http://3v4l.org/s956I

Comment: Can you show us all the code you're using to convert the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following code gives

```
Booker’s
B
o
o
k
e
r
�
�
�
s

66
111
111
107
101
114
226
128
153
115

B
o
o
k
e
r
’
s
66
111
111
107
101
114
8217
115
```

Note: your `header()` has an extra apostrophe.
The difference is using mb_* functions. ’ is the unicode apostrophe [See this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm). It is what AJAX is returning. It is a multibyte character and must be handled with mb_* functions.

```
    <?php     
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $string = "Booker’s";
    echo $string  . "<br>";

    $atext = stringToArray($string);
    foreach ($atext as $text ){
        echo $text . "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";

    foreach ($atext as $text ){
        echo ord($text) . "<br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";


    // mb_convert_encoding($string,'utf-8');
    $atext = mbStringToArray($string);

    foreach ($atext as $text ){
        echo $text . "<br>";
   }

    foreach ($atext as $text ){
        echo uniord($text) . "<br>";
   }

  function uniord($c){
    $ord0 = ord($c{0}); if ($ord0>=0   && $ord0<=127) return $ord0;                                                                  // 0bbbbbbb => 1 byte
    if  ($ord0>=127 && $ord0<=191 && strlen($c)==1){       
      echo "Invalid utf-8 character: " .$c."\r\n";
      return "";
    }
    $ord1 = ord($c{1});
    if ($ord0>=192 && $ord0<=223){
      return ($ord0-192)*64 + ($ord1-128);     // 110bbbbb  (192 mask) => 2 bytes
    }
    $ord2 = ord($c{2});
    if ($ord0>=224 && $ord0<=239){
      return ($ord0-224)*4096 + ($ord1-128)*64 + ($ord2-128); // 1110bbbb  (224 mask) => 3 bytes
    }
    $ord3 = ord($c{3});
    if ($ord0>=240 && $ord0<=247){
      return ($ord0-240)*262144 + ($ord1-128)*4096 + ($ord2-128)*64 + ($ord3-128);  // 11110bbb  (240 mask) => 4 bytes
    }

    echo "Invalid utf-8 character\r\n";
    return false;
  }


function mbStringToArray ($string) {
    $array = array();
    $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    while ($strlen) {
        $array[] = mb_substr($string,0,1,"UTF-8");
        $string = mb_substr($string,1,$strlen,"UTF-8");
        $strlen = mb_strlen($string);
    }
    return $array; }

function stringToArray ($string) {
    $array = array();
    $strlen = strlen($string);
    while ($strlen) {
        $array[] = substr($string,0,1);
        $string = substr($string,1,$strlen);
        $strlen = strlen($string);
    }
    return $array; }

?>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused here.. You're returning 8217 for the apostrophe? What I want to do is convert all apostrophes to `'`.

Comment: I've update the post to make it more consistent. To answer your question, `&#8217;` is the unicode apostrophe [See this.](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm). It is what AJAX is returning. It is a multibyte character and must be handled with `mb_*` string functions.

Comment: Thanks for the update and the effort on this, I truly appreciate the help. You know, I have to say, this whole thing with the character encoding is a HUGE PITA. Why is it so difficult to convert these smart quotes?

Comment: So, is it the AJAX that's returning the multibyte characters? If I save an apostrophe (#039;), it will render properly even though it was sent through AJAX.

Comment: Glad to help. When I started reading / writing jpeg headers, I needed to do a lot of research to finally understand muti-byte character sets. A good tutorial can be [found here](http://www.zehnet.de/2005/02/12/unicode-utf-8-tutorial/). If you use, `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` it will render properly. I've updated the code above to reflect this. You can also replace it with `&#039` to simplify, but as long as your encoding is utf-8, it should be fine as is.

Comment: Let me ask you a couple more questions if you don't mind. Character encoding seems to be an area that not many devs seem to understand in depth, myself included. If I take your code that you've posted exactly as it is and run it, I get `Booker�s`. Now, the string isn't coming from ajax but from from within your code. Is this right? Should I be getting the `�` instead of the apostrophe? By the way, thank you for the link, I've bookmarked it and will read through ut

Comment: Yes this is right. My code uses the same multi-byte apostrophe that you posted above. You should not be getting the `�`. When I run just the first 3 lines of my code above, I get `Booker’s`. The supported font set can also impact what is displayed. The link I posted has a link at the top titled `Fonts that support U+2019` - Make sure the browser font you are displaying is in this list (default browser font). You may have to specify the display font. That is the only reason I can think of that you are getting your result.

Comment: Use the console (F12 in many browsers) font tab to discover which font is being displayed.

Comment: OK, thank you again for all your help. Yes, I can also get `Booker’s` when I run the first three lines of your code. It's when I run that string through your functions that it comes back with the funky question mark. Can you tell me which function I should be using to convert my string coming from AJAX? Is it `mbStringToArray` or `stringToArray`?

Comment: `mbStringToArray` allows you to print out each character's value for multibyte characters. `stringToArray` prints out each character's value for single byte character strings (shown only for comparison so you could see what was happening). You shouldn't need to convert your string if you set the charset to `utf8` if you use the `header()` fn you already have at the top. When I used your `convertQuote` fn, it did correctly replace the quote.

Comment: I am still playing with what you've posted and I see now that `mbStringToArray` is what I need. To test, I tried the single byte function and I see that's basically giving me what I had to begin with. One last question if you don't mind. I want to convert the `&#8217;` html entity to `&#030;`, where would I do that in your code?

Comment: I believe you mean `&#030;`... You can insert `$converted = convertQuote($string);` right after `$string` is set. Your string should no longer contain the multi-byte character - but depending on where your data is coming from, other multi-byte characters could exist. Why not leave it alone? With `utf8` set properly, all should display correctly.

Comment: OK, I'll just leave it as it is. My friend, thank you very much for all of your help and staying with me on this. When I'm done, I plan to read the link you provided. Thanks again for all of your help!